# Question regarding Opportunity Zone investing

Tags: s-corporation

With Opportunity Zones, you have 180 days to reinvest capital gains.  I have capital gains from the sale of land through an S Corporation.  I have received a K-1 outlining those gains from the S Corporation.  However, I'm having a hard time figuring out when those gains are recognized by me as the individual (thus when does the clock start on the 180 day timeframe for the Opportunity Zone investment).  Is it when the actual sale of land occurred, or is it at the end of the fiscal year for the S Corporation?  Or some other time?

Comment: Whenever that money came into your Corp's possession. Mike Brady